# Anime where two brother search for power stones; one of them uses the devil stone and they fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

I think I have seen it about 7-8 years ago.

All I can remember is that there were two brothers who where looking for some power stones to do something. One of them used the devil stone, which was not good, and then they fought each other.

The anime was not *Brave Story*.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I'm sure you can remember more than this. Was it in colour? What language did you watch it on? Was it Japanese animation or Western? How old were the brothers? What were there names? What did the "devil stone" look like? What magical powers did these stones possess?

Comment: Of course it was in colour .the animation was in Japanese and the brothers were about 20 or older and there was a girl with them witch they love her both . the devil stone was hexagonal and red and it was on the forehead of one of the brothers.